# Не отображаются ошибки валидации

Tags: php, html, form, symfony, twig

template

```
         {{ form_start(form, {'action': path('update_customer', {id: customer.id}), 'method': 'PUT'}) }}
            <div class="my-custom-class-for-errors">
                {{ form_errors(form) }}
            </div>

        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {#{form_widget(form._token)}#}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Type

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstName', TextType::class, [
            'constraints' => [new Length(['min' => 3])]
        ])
        ->add('lastName', TextType::class)
        ->add('email', TextType::class)
        ->add('phoneNumber', TextType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class);

}
```

контроллер

```
   public function update($id, Request $request, ValidatorInterface $validator): RedirectResponse
{
    $firstName = $request->request->all()['customer']['firstName'];

    $submittedToken = $this->tokenManager->getToken('customer')->getValue();

    if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('customer', $submittedToken)) {

        $customer = $this->customerRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);

        empty($firstName) ? true : $customer->setFirstName($firstName);
        empty($request->request->all()['customer']['lastName']) ? true : $customer->setLastName($request->request->all()['customer']['lastName']);
        empty($request->request->all()['customer']['email']) ? true : $customer->setEmail($request->request->all()['customer']['email']);
        empty($request->request->all()['customer']['phoneNumber']) ? true : $customer->setPhoneNumber($request->request->all()['customer']['phoneNumber']);

        $this->customerRepository->updateCustomer($customer);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('all_customer');
    }

    throw new \Exception('Invalid token');
}
```

Не отображаются ошибки валидации в темплейте.

Comment: А вы в контролере не забыли вызвать метод для проверик валидности формы ```$form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()```?

Comment: @UKRman а у меня в контроллере нету form можете скинуть реализацию этого всего с учетом моего кода?

Comment: @UKRman я гуглил про то, что вы говорите, но что-то у меня не сходится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как создать форму и про валидировать ее в symfony, [документацыя](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html):

```
MyController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/test", name="test")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function request(Request $request): Response
    {
        $command = new Command();

        $form = $this->createForm(Form::class, $command);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            try {
                //Ваш код связан с оброботкой класа Command

                return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
            } catch (\DomainException $e) {
                $this->addFlash('error', $e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        return $this->render('app/test.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}

class Form extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add('firstName', TextType::class, [
            'constraints' => [new Length(['min' => 3])]
        ])
        ->add('lastName', TextType::class)
        ->add('email', TextType::class)
        ->add('phoneNumber', TextType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Command::class,
        ]);
    }
}

class Command
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $firstName;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $lastName;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $email;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $phoneNumber;
}
```

Comment: один момент у меня route /edit/{id} мне бы как-то с этим придумать

Comment: No route found for "POST /customer/edit/29": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET)

Comment: Ну я так понимаю что у вас два екшена, один в качестве view другой в качестве сохранения. Перенесите код в один и уберите параметр Verb на конкретный тип запроса

Comment: UKRman можете написать это в коде пожалуйста.